# elastic search query with lists of keywords

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to perform a full-text search on the textfield of a number of documents stored in an elasticsearch database where the text field of the result documents have to contain a number of keywords and not contain a number of keywords. So I have 2 lists of strings called `includes` and `excludes` where all the strings in `includes` must be in the document and all the strings in `excludes` must not be in the documents text field.

Answer (score 0):

[Try bool query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html)

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool" : {
      "must" : [{
        "term" : { "text" : "keyword1" }
      },{
        "term" : { "text" : "keyword2" }
      }],
      "must_not" :[{
        "term" : { "text" : "keyword3" }
      },{
        "term" : { "text" : "keyword4" }
      }]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: when you put space between the keywords in a term query the default in elasticsearch is the OR operator but what I'm after is the equivalent query just where it puts AND between the keywords. so documents where keyword1 AND keyword2 AND keyword  AND NOT( keyword3 AND keyword5 AND keyword6) exist

Comment: @AliJanalizadeh True. Then you can split these